Sister termite eaten 2 x6 cut down-pt or just regular doug fir?
we are original homeowners to a built in mid-1992 in Southern California and for the last year, we have been having a termite company treating a downstairs closet wall that the other side is an enclosed garage.
So on inside the closet is 5/8 drywall, 3/8 plywood, the cavity for studs and mechanicals, then 3/8 plywood again and 5/8 drywall facing the inside garage.
On the closet side I removed some of the drywall and plywood so the company can get a good look and we found only 1 2x6 stud that has been severely eaten; no signs of an termite life still around.
Termite company did a treatment again and said he would be ok now to sister the stud then start the process to put everything back together which includes new insulation, plywood and drywall.
I have a pic attached of the bottom part of that stud and though a 2x6, you can see the builder put in a big notch at the bottom so not really 2x6 going all the way down.
We can see that the top foot or so of the stud has no decay so I should be able to get my palm nailer up there and sister to some meat in the existing stud.
My questions are: for that sister stud, should I use some pressure treated like the sill and use 2x6 or just regular doug fir? I don't mind spending the extra money just in case termites return to the decayed stud.
If so use pt, should I use the greenish color brand I see at our local lumber yard or should I use the brownish pt at that same lumber yard or safe to use the brown pt ground contact that HD sells?
My research was showing if using pt then I should use hot dipped galvanized nails?
The bottom of the existing stud pretty eaten so to get a better bit between that and the sister should I use some kind of bolts and a plate on the left of the eaten stud as .just nails may not get much of a hold.
Thanks for any advice.


For studs, just placing the second stud beside the bad one is good, unless just using a partial stud, one that does not go all the way up.

I hope this isn't a structural wall.

I added a pic of the major support next to the decayed stud and same is 7 feet to the left of that one. I also see the decayed and stud to the left builder cut down to only 2.5 inches on the sill plate. I would think if structural that would not be cutdown.....

If you use pt, all that will happen is that any termites which get that far will eat something else nearby. Unless you have reason to believe that this piece is more at risk then any other nearby framing, the gains seem minimal. And PT is somewhat notorious for being sold wet, so it may be even more prone to warping as it dries than the usual white wood, unless you're careful about what and where you purchase. On the other hand, outside of the warping and cost issues and teathing kids, there is no strong reason not to use pressure treated wood for indoor construction, as I understand it.
